# What is the translation of the lyrics in Moana's "We Know the Way"?

Tags: music, disney, translation, moana

I was a bit disappointed to find out that the subtitles for the *Moana* Blu-ray did not include the original *or* translated lyrics for "We Know the Way".

Here's the song in full, and the beginning of the song is done in Tokelauan:

[This Bustle article](https://www.bustle.com/articles/196387-the-translation-of-we-know-the-way-from-moana-makes-perfect-sense) attempts to translate the lyrics, however they don't use  Tokelauan, but try to guesstimate a translation based on Samoan, Māori and Google Translate. Part of this reason is that [only ~3,200 speak the language](http://archive.ethnologue.com/15/show_language.asp?code=tkl) in the entire world.

But is there an official translation somewhere?

Comment: The beginning of the song is Samoan. The chorus is Tokelauan. Also, Tokelauan is generally understood by people that speak te reo Māori or Samoan.

Comment: @TonyMeyer Which parts? I've watched an interview with the songwriter say it "starts Samoan and then Tokelauan", but you say the "Chorus" is Tokelauan, but I'm not sure where exactly that starts.

Comment: I haven't seen it, but does *Moana* qualify as fantasy??

Comment: @ThePopMachine Yes, very much so, thus my asking it here and not on [movies.se].

Comment: @CreationEdge:   Can you elaborate??

Comment: @ThePopMachine [The film tells the story of Moana, the strong-willed daughter of the chief of a Polynesian tribe, who is chosen by the ocean itself to reunite a mystical relic with a goddess. When a blight strikes her island, Moana sets sail in search of Maui, a legendary demigod, in the hope of saving her people.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moana_(2016_film))

Comment: I don't know Tokelauan, and know only small bits of Samoan, so this is a guess (but from someone that lives in the largest Polynesian city, so hears a lot of these languages), but I think it's from "Aue aue". I could find someone to ask if you really want to know. This interview with Foa'i talks about it a bit: http://thespinoff.co.nz/music/15-02-2017/this-is-our-movie-opetaia-foai-on-keeping-moana-authentic-through-music/

Comment: @TonyMeyer Thanks, that makes sense, too, since Aue Aue is reused in the English chorus.

Answer (score 62):

### Yes, there's an official translation.

As I was writing the question, I finally found this information. Previously, when I attempted to find this information, it did not come up in my searches (which was months ago), but has now become one of the top results in my search. (I blame/thank indexing).

Te Vaka, the musical group that performed that portion of the song and was founded by Opetaia Foa'i who co-wrote "We Know the Way", [posted this to their official Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/OfficialTeVaka/posts/10154737022156934):

> Now that the full movie version of "We know the way" is available on itunes, here is something special for our fans. Here are the full original lyrics and translations of this song:
> WE KNOW THE WAY - Lyrics
> *Tatou o tagata folau e vala’auina
>
> E le atua o le sami tele e o mai
>
> Ia ava’e le lu’itau e lelei
>
> Tapenapena
>
> Ua malamalama uiga o le moana
>
> Va’ai I fetu ma isi failoga e maua ai ala
>
> O nu’u fou avea mo tatou aiga
>
> Aue aue
>
> nuku i mua
>
> Te manulele e tataki e
>
> Aue aue
>
> te fenua te malie
>
> Nae ko hakilia mo kaiga e*

(Removed the English portion for brevity)

> WE KNOW THE WAY - Translations
> We are voyagers
> summoned by the mighty gods
> of this mighty ocean to come
> we take up the good challenge
> get ready
> We know the ways of the sea
> we look to the stars and other signs
> to find our way
> to discover new lands
> to make our home
> oh! oh!
> there is land up ahead
> a bird in flight to take us there<sup>1</sup>
> oh! oh!
> this beautiful land
> the place i was looking for
> we will make our home

Opetaia also clarifies that the languages used are Samoan and *then* Tokelauan, not just Tokelauan.

I've transcribed the relevant portion here (but without the "ums" and such):

> The words in Samoan and then Tokelauan just says:
> *We are voyagers called to the sea
>
> Called by the great god of the sea
>
> Who gives us a challenge/puts up a challenge
>
> We take on that good challenge
>
> So, prepare
>
> We know the ways of the sea
>
> Via the skies and the currents, etcetera*
> All those words are in there.

Keep in mind, though, that was an off-the-top-of-his-head recounting of the *meaning*, not necessarily the translation (as evident with the "etcetera").

<sup>1</sup>While I was looking into this, I found out that the "bird in flight" is a common theme when referencing land while out at sea. This is because birds tend to fly towards or be near land, so once they're clearly visible, land is generally close. At that point, you could start following birds instead of stars for the final stretch.

Comment: Excellent self-answer!

Comment: @Mooz And not originally my intent! When I wanted to get this info months ago I couldn't find it. Maybe I was just inept then, but I've wanted to know this ever since I saw it in the theater. It's my favorite part of my favorite song in the movie.

Comment: @CreationEdge Inept or you've levelled up your Google Fu.